# Existence of density

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $ \{ D_i : i \geq 1 \} $ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables taking values $ \{ 0, 1, 2, \dotsc, K-1 \} $ where $ K \geq 3 $ is a positive integer with probabilities $ \mathbb{P} ( D_1 = j) = \alpha_j $ for $ j = 0, 1, \dotsc, K-1$. Consider the random variable 
\begin{equation*}
X = \sum_{ i = 1}^{\infty} D_i K^{-i} .
\end{equation*}
Under what conditions on $ \alpha_j$'s, $ X $ will admit a density i.e., its distribution will be absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure?

Comment: If and only if $\alpha_j=1/K$ for every $j$. Now that you have the answer, please tell us your thoughts.